# VS Code ripper-tags extension not generating ctag file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ctags, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=otoniel-isidoro.vscode-ruby-ctags) to use CTAGS through ripper-tags is not generating a ctag file:

```
Error on generate tags:'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ripper-tags-0.3.4/lib/ripper-tags' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

The settings.json file:

```
// settings.json
{
"ctags": {
    "executePath": "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ripper-tags-0.3.4/lib/ripper-tags",
    "options": "--tag-file=.tags --recursive --force --exclude=/assets/ --exclude=.bundle --exclude=.git/ --exclude=coverage/ --exclude=.arcanist-extensions/ --exclude=log/ --exclude=tmp/ --exclude=bin/",
    "fileName": ".tags"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by cutting the configuration to:

```
{
"ctags": {
    "fileName": ".tags"
}
}
```